# Android MQTT async subscribe

Tags: android, asynchronous, mqtt, paho, subscribe

I just start use MQTT Paho library in my app. 
How to make an asynchronous subscription to the topic? (subscription in new thread)
And then in real time to receive the data and display.

It's my code in MainActivity, in main thread:

```
public void mqttConnect () {
    final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sub_Text_View);
    String clientId = MqttClient.generateClientId();
    final MqttAndroidClient client = new MqttAndroidClient(this.getApplicationContext(), server, clientId);
    client.setCallback(new MqttCallbackExtended() {
        @Override
        public void connectComplete(boolean reconnect, String serverURI) {

        }

        @Override
        public void connectionLost(Throwable cause) {

        }

        @Override
        public void messageArrived(String topic, MqttMessage message) throws Exception {
            Log.d("NANADEV", message.toString());
            textView.setText(message.toString());

        }

        @Override
        public void deliveryComplete(IMqttDeliveryToken token) {

        }
    });

    MqttConnectOptions mqttConnectOptions = new MqttConnectOptions();
    mqttConnectOptions.setAutomaticReconnect(true);
    mqttConnectOptions.setCleanSession(false);

    try {
        client.connect(mqttConnectOptions, null, new IMqttActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(IMqttToken asyncActionToken) {

                final String topic = "testwork/value";
                int qos =0;
                try {
                    IMqttToken subToken = client.subscribe(topic, qos);
                    subToken.setActionCallback(new IMqttActionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(IMqttToken asyncActionToken) {



                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(IMqttToken asyncActionToken, Throwable exception) {

                        }
                    });
                } catch (MqttException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(IMqttToken asyncActionToken, Throwable exception) {

            }
        });
    } catch (MqttException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: You haven't told us why this doesn't work. Edit the question and explain the problems you have when you try the code you have shared

Answer (score 0):

In your oncreate

```
private String uniqueID;
String ip="brokerip";
String port="brokerport usaly 1883"
String broker = "tcp://" + ip + ":" + port;

uniqueID = android.provider.Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), android.provider.Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);

IMqttAsyncClient client= new MqttAsyncClient(broker, uniqueID, new MemoryPersistence());
mqttClient.subscribe("YOURTOPIC/", 0);
mqttClient.subscribe("YOUROTHERTOPIC", 0);
```

and then in your method:

```
public void messageArrived(String topic, MqttMessage msg) throws Exception {
    Log.i("mqttarrival", "Message arrived from topic " + topic);

    if (topic.equals("YOURTOPIC")) {
        System.out.println(msg.toString());
    }     
    else {
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I recommend you [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).